# parsing a JSON array from a string

Tags: android, json

can some one please get me the json parsing for an json array

```
 line = "contexts": [
    {
        "uuid": "6686feaa-a254-42ec-a662-c36f70f7a586",
        "name": "School",
    },
    {
        "uuid": "bd8e6c44-d461-4bbe-8946-a3717dc7fa7f",
        "name": "Teaching",
    }]
```

I need uuid and name into to string arrays. I tried

```
String[] x = new String[10];
String[] y = new String[10];
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(line);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){          
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    x = json_data.getString("name");
y = json_data.getString("uuid");            
        }
```

I get type mismatch error when I run this. The type of line is string which I return from server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `i` to add elements to Array's:

```
String[] x = new String[10];
String[] y = new String[10];
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(line);
JSONArray jArray =json.getJSONArray("contexts");

for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){          
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    x[i] = json_data.getString("name");
    y[i] = json_data.getString("uuid");            
        }
```

you can use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ for checking json is valid or not. and use `ArrayList` instead of `Array` for getting items dynamically from web service

Comment: @user1494754 : most welcome friend!!!:) . as i suggest u don't use String Array for getting data from web service. you can use any Collection for it like ArrayList,List,HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

Its neither JSONObject, nor JSONArray, return string from server like below:

```
line = {"contexts": [
    {
        "uuid": "6686feaa-a254-42ec-a662-c36f70f7a586",
        "name": "School",
    },
    {
        "uuid": "bd8e6c44-d461-4bbe-8946-a3717dc7fa7f",
        "name": "Teaching",
    }]}
```

and then parse like below code:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(line);
JSONArray jArray =json.getJSONArray("contexts");
```

Comment: Now thats perfect, every Json must be start with an Object `{` or with an Array `[`.